# Positive values with kernel function in R

Tags: r, kernel-density

How could we get only positive values using kernel function in R (eg: when estimating product's price)?

Answer (score 1):

The `density()` function has an argument `from` that can be used for cases like this. So try:

```
density(x, from=0)
```